# Optimization for system views

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a query for getting columns data from the Microsoft SQL Server database. I need to speed up my query because I will run it multiple times each minute. Currently, my query took about 60ms to execute on SQL Server. It would be awesome too cut it down to 30 or 40ms.

Execution plan: [plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyF8enSdL)

Is there any possible way for optimization?

```
SELECT 
    c.name as 'columnName',
    t.name as 'dataType',
    t.name + '(' + cast(c.max_length as varchar(50)) +')' AS 'dataTypeFull', 
    ISNULL(sep.value,'') AS 'columnDescription',
    CASE 
      WHEN fk.object_id is not null THEN fk.name ELSE NULL 
    END AS 'foreignKey',
    pk_tab.*,
    ISNULL(i.is_primary_key,0) AS 'primaryKey'
  FROM
    sys.tables tab
  INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns c ON c.object_id = tab.object_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id = c.object_id AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.indexes i ON ic.object_id = i.object_id AND ic.index_id = i.index_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.foreign_key_columns fk_cols ON fk_cols.parent_object_id = tab.object_id
                AND fk_cols.parent_column_id = c.column_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.foreign_keys fk ON fk.object_id = fk_cols.constraint_object_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.tables pk_tab ON pk_tab.object_id = fk_cols.referenced_object_id
  LEFT JOIN 
    sys.extended_properties sep ON c.object_id = sep.major_id 
                AND c.column_id = sep.minor_id 
                AND sep.name = 'MS_Description'
  JOIN 
    sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
  WHERE 
    c.object_id = Object_id('some-table-name')
```

Comment: We'd need to see your [execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/).

Comment: Try [updating system table statistics](https://www.dbdelta.com/sql-server-system-table-statistics-update/). Consider specifying `WHERE tab.object_id` instead of `WHERE c.object_id`, although it probably won't affect performance.

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyF8enSdL @DaleK

Comment: [edit] it into the question - its the most important information you have.

Comment: For just getting the schema of the table, `sp_describe_first_result_set` on a `SELECT TOP(0) * FROM table` is a lot more efficient. This will not retrieve foreign keys, but that could be done separately. Ultimately, having to retrieve metadata "fast" is always going to be a problem because the system views aren't optimized for it -- but it's also unlikely that you need it because you probably don't have a database where schemas actually change multiple times each minute. If you do, focus on not having to do that; if you don't, invest in caching this information instead.

Comment: I don't want to have multiple queries. Maybe I will need to cache